# RSA decrypt message with given private key string with openssl library in C

Tags: c++, c, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to use openssl to decrypt a encrypted string, which I already have the private key as a string. However, the function RSA_private_decrypt() always failed.

As I found mostly a private key is stored as a .pem file, therefore I made one:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----
MIICdAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl4wggJaAgEAAoGBAMFFU2p/iSbAmx5VxQFoVPY2rzHvn2OIJbflFqaIvwndiOuVzkLMRBzxg3WueWKWmBREHPPy
mZQHgx8B0O0xoF6VfLQd9a41++Nz5DTKJVNJIPokbF7UznGQgH7IvHUMvl0+rcqToOO7y9KULy/dp2IhAN1sgHCdwsfxs8ih6UdnAgMBAAECgYANDWuGw7o1
fch8EfrOD4e9YRAP5Uj0Zdt2Qeh3ssCEIAwBLQrTBAyNj9n69p+IAveeVsNFzlqE3sUCMRM1Eabs3hVB7/P/WafZWrm0JZ1c6MkuK4yV9I0juwEYLx8fMSuw
qCGvOnyVdR+8M2/o7cnmNAG7FlfBgZbcQaoiDv+4kQJBAPqrURowSJHsPDqww+46MzBM3CJPujjp4grWmq59i+j6f4aAHgGEDmcPY/UU6PUhluW7X5awvxVs
clqS2TyB6hsCQQDFYYXhTVyFrwB+x3X9CAPcyRKDg6B+j/txfNKfUWbAWEspwap6hlY3Ky1PZIW9cRZt09SXS5h3xhcXvgtw3mylAkBRt8nfxL/TunTEGV42
aojHhTb6hI1MAosrR1zz53/V+tvaCChADEH5vR20BxYO291qlVQLNyGEJW9+MYNaY2vjAkALQHv5VAeqN0e38nbvbb2KoIvFo4NKs7qJxavcGS/aVy4xuzCU
u4O+sV9r3zcgjYnRyPmdhlmyukAmwla0oHlhAj96U73bpEiNpda5mZmzmv3mSDPCwAClGTtvjPE/1c0ujSXWyTE9/f33NczZVia8nfnLErTQLtp/W601dt1c
JQA=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and read the .pem file with PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(), then decrypt the string with the key, as following code shows:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>


static RSA * create_rsa(uint8_t *key)
{
    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    BIO *keybio ;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    if (keybio == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create key BIO.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    return rsa;
}

int main() {

    int privatekeyfd = open("/tmp/qxuser.pem", O_RDONLY);
    if (privatekeyfd < 0) {
        printf("open /tmp/qxuser.pem error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    uint8_t buf[1024];
    int n = read(privatekeyfd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("read error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    close(privatekeyfd);
    printf("read qxuser.pem len: %d\n", n);

    RSA* rsa = create_rsa(buf);
    if (rsa == NULL) {
        printf("create_rsa error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    const char* encrypt =
        "So0NH7b2uJZ7KApmBq98CzV7MSUu1XmleaDIqYC1OzUfih5gCvsvd+jChSEiqal8E69ghl+MhQ6+";

    int res = RSA_private_decrypt(strlen((const char*)encrypt), (const unsigned char*)encrypt,
              buf, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    if (res < 0) {
        printf("RSA_private_decrypt error: %d\n", res);
        return -1;
    }
    buf[res] = 0;
    printf("decrypt: %s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Any hints are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Use of strlen() here is very dangerous as "encrypt" could contain null bytes and cause strlen to return an incorrect size. Which errors do you get when running your sample ?

Comment: Another aspect, if "encrypt" is base64 encoded, you probably need to first decode it to a raw byte string before passing it to RSA_private_decrypt().

Comment: The key seems to be in PKCS#8 format. But the header and footer line belong to PKCS#1 format (also missing a hyphen in the header line).
The key is a 1024 bit key, i.e. the message should also be 1024 bit = 128 byte long. However, the posted message is only 57 bytes long after Base64 decoding. There is something wrong with your data.

Comment: The header / footer for that key should read `PRIVATE KEY` rather than `RSA PRIVATE KEY`... the fact that it is an RSA key is already indicated within the hex encoded binary. You'd then probably need to use `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` too, if the API makes any sense. Do test if the function fails or not, always check your data input routines!